# Is working oneself grey an idiom?

Tags: idioms

In the *Broken Angels* sci-fi book by Richard Morgan, I found the following sentence:

> Wardani worked herself grey.

*Wardani* is the name of a woman. The general sense should be that she worked a lot, but I do not know where it comes from. I assumed it is an idiom but I could not find it anywhere on the Web. Is it an idiom? Is the meaning working hard?

Comment: In context it's probably "comprehensible", but it's not idiomatically established. Morgan's is the *only* instance of ***worked herself grey*** in the entire *25 million* books indexed by Google, but there are in fact 3 separate instances of [***worked himself grey***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22worked+himself+grey%22) in books published in the last 70 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's common enough to count as a idiom, but it combines the ideas of stress causing  grey hair and working until you are old and grey quite nicely.